# Как преобразовать QByteArray в изображение и поместить его в QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, изображения, qimage

Принимаю из последовательного порта байты, пишу в `QByteArray` и передаю на обработку в кастомный `QGraphicsView` (Чтоб потом реализовать зум и панарамирование). Каждый байт - цвет пикселя черно-белого изображения от `\x00`, до `\xFF`. В `PyQt5` все делается очень просто, я создаю метод у `QGraphicsView`:

```
def set_pixmap(self, msg, w_img, h_img):
print msg
print [msg]
self._zoom = 0
self.img_width = w_img
self.img_height = h_img
self.qImg = QImage(msg, w_img, h_img, w_img, QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
self._photo = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(self.qImg))
self._photo.mousePressEvent = self.pixelSelect
self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
```

В `msg` передаю строку байт и её преобразовываю в `QImage`, его в `QPixmap`, затем в `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, а его уже помещаю в `QGraphicsScene`. Все работает как часы, все просто и понятно. В `C++`-жеж, полная неразбериха.
Передаю `QByteArray`, ширину и высоту:

```
void ImageViewer::setPixmapImage(QByteArray image_data, int image_width, int image_height
{
    zoom = 0;
    qDebug() << image_data;
}
```

Этот `qDebug` выводит все правильно - `"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"` (посылаю 4 белых пикселя 2х2), но что делать потом?

Согласно докам, `QImage` можно создать только из `uchar`'ов. Каким образом преобразовать данные из `QByteArray` в нужный формат? Япробовал через `memcpy`, но что-то идет не так, мусор, набивающийся в `uchar[int]` при создании так там и остается ... :

```
unsigned char data[image_resolution];
qDebug() << data;
memcpy(data, image_data.toStdString().c_str(), image_resolution);
qDebug() << data;
qImg = QImage(data, image_width, image_height, image_width, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
qDebug() << qImg.byteCount();
```

Что первый, что второй `qDebug()` выводят `0xc2d42c`. Однако `qImg` создается, и третий `qDebug()` выдает правильные 4 байта. И вообще, все правильно ... Воткак так-то? а? Как так-то? Вчера сидел всю ночь, не вышло, а как только начал писать сюда, и прошел по все стадиям, чтоб описать проблему,  - прочитал пару статей и все получилось ... Спасибо тебе `stackoverflow`, ты помогаешь даже без ответов!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кому понадобится, то вот рабочий код:

```
QImage qImg = QImage((uchar*)image_data.data (), imgInfo.img_width,
                            imgInfo.img_height, imgInfo.img_width,
                            QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(qImg);
QGraphicsPixmapItem * Pix = scene->addPixmap(pixmap);
```